# How can I make this query in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I can't find how to make this query

```sql
SELECT * FROM paquetes
WHERE (
    SELECT estatuses.nombre FROM estatus_paquete
    INNER JOIN estatuses ON estatuses.id = estatus_paquete.estatus_id
    WHERE (estatus_paquete.paquete_id = paquetes.id)
    ORDER BY estatus_paquete.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
) = 'En envio'
AND paquetes.deleted_at IS NULL
```

Comment: Also, try to code it yourself, don't expect us to convert a raw query into code

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky query, but you can make it line by line with the following syntax.

```php
$query = DB::query()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('paquetes')
    ->where(function ($sub) {
        $sub->select('estatuses.nombre')
            ->from('estatus_paquete')
            ->join('estatuses', 'estatuses.id', 'estatus_paquete.estatus_id')
            ->whereColumn(['estatus_paquete.paquete_id', 'paquetes.id'])
            ->orderByDesc('estatus_paquete.created_at')
            ->limit(1);
    }, 'En envio')
    ->whereNull('paquetes.deleted_at');

// dump($query->toSql());
$query->get();
```

Comment: Why answer questions that do not show minimal effort?

Comment: Boredom. And I like translating weird sql queries to eloquent. If comments allowed blockcode markdown, I'd have put it there.

Comment: Ok, thats an understandable reason :-) . ( off the record, it's not eloquent, but the  DB query builder)